# What is meant by atomicity of write operations in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

In MongoDB documentation it states that write operations are atomic at the document level. What does this mean?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can't have atomic operations that span several documents.

Money transfer, for example. You deduct funds from one wallet, add to another. You can't do that atomically in mongodb.

In case you didn't know what "atomically" means, it is "operation either succeeds as a whole or fails as a whole. It can't have only some parts of it succeed and others fail".

Comment: what is `Transaction` then ?

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi: transactions (which offer atomicity of updates across several documents) did not exist at the time of the answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please look at the edit queue and accept or decline them, it is full and we can not add more information to your answer.

Comment: @KasirBarati: I don't see pending edits for this answer.